Why does GIMP darken my image if I create a new visible layer?
Dear Photography community,
I recently started using Gimp and I noticed that every time I create a new layer from the latest visible picture (New from Visible), the whole picture darkens.
The setting of the new layer is:

Mode 'Normal'
Opacity 100%

How can I prevent this effect?

Better asked in GraphicsDesign. But well, shouldn't happen. Provide link to XCF in new question over there.

@xenoid GIMP is on-topic here, just like PS, if they're used in a photgraphic context.

I can reproduce your problem if the source layer isn't 100% opaque. You may not notice the background checkerboard or the check style is set to a uniform light color:

After:

If this is not the case, please edit your question to add to your question a screenshot of the Layers list, before and after.

Hi Xenoid, thank you for your response. When I work on the picture from scratch it indeed doesn't change. So probably I caused this issue somehow.
